# Information Retrieval Get place name by image

Tags: image, search, image-processing, google-api, information-retrieval

I am starting the development of a software in which through an image of a touristic spot (for example: San Peter Basilica, the Colosseum, etc.) I should retrieve which is the name of the spot (plus its related information). In addition to the image I will have with me the picture coordinates (embedded as metadata). I know I can support me with Google Images API using reverse search in which I give my image as an input, and I will have as a response a big set of images.

However, my advice request for you, is that now having all the similar images, which approach can I make in order to retrieve the correct place name which is in the photo.

A second approach that I am managing is to construct my own dataset in my database, and do my own heuristic (filtering images by their location and then to make the comparation over the resulting subset after having done that filtering). Suggestions and advices are heard, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to use the captions of the images (if available) as a query, retrieve a list of candidates and make use of a structured knowledge base to deduce the location name.

The situation is lot trickier if there're no captions associated with the images, in which case, you may use the fc7 layer output of a pre-trained convolutional net and query into the ImageNet to retrieve a ranked list of related images. Since those images have captions, you could again use them to get the location name.